# SearchView expand/collapse animation in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

**What I Have**

I have a SearchView which does its work perfectly. But when I touch on it, it appears and disappears out of nothing. There is no transition animation playing on it and so it doesn't look good.

**What I Want**

I want a simple slide left and slide right animation to be played on the SearchView when it is expanded and collapsed respectively.

**What I Tried**

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
//Get the ID for the search bar LinearLayout
int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
//Get the search bar Linearlayout
LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
//Give the Linearlayout a transition animation.
searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

but the searchBar is always null so I can't set the layout transition on it.

Can I get a solution for it? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Can any one post a suggestion here?

Comment: I know it's too late but I hope the following link will help if still, you're looking for the answer.
[Android Search View Sample](https://github.com/jaisonfdo/SearchViewSample)

Answer (score 12):

You can actually just grab the LinearLayout by doing the following:

```
LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
```

So this is what you should write instead,

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
final int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);  // Remove this line 

//  The modified Line
LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);  

searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

Comment: Yes, the searchBar is not null now and there is no NullPointerException anymore. But the animation is not like the one I want. There is no slide left/slide right animation on expand/collapse. I will accept the answer once I get the full answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with the full solution?

Comment: A strange animations is still an animation... Thx @Steven!

Comment: Thank you! You saved smoky of my screen)))

Answer (score 4):

After reading the @Steven answer I got the solution given below

inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method write the code

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.meet_people_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

and here is my meet_people_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.jz.cso.activities.MeetPeopleActivity">
<item
    android:title=""
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    ></item>
</menu>
```

Comment: That was a clean animation

Answer (score 0):

```
View searchBar = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
if (searchBar != null && searchBar instanceof LinearLayout) {
     ((LinearLayout) searchBar).setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
}
```